# Filebeat to splunk

Tags: splunk, filebeat

Is there a way to use filebeat to forward logs to splunk? Has anyone tried that?

We use filebeat to forward logs to ELK stack and want the same forwarder to be able to forward logs to splunk

Answer (score 2):

You can use Splunk HEC to receive Filebeat data via logstash

https://medium.com/@epatro/how-to-forward-events-from-logstash-to-splunk-4f2608041feb